# How to optimize code that multiplies every row and column in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find a way to optimize my code, and I have difficulties in finding a right way. First I'm adding numbers in empty array and after that, I'm multiplying every row and column using pure logic, **without any php function** that could help me out. For now I've tried to calculate rows and columns in one nested for loop, but it doesn't work.

```
$nxmArr = [];

$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;

$value = 1;

for( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )
{
  for( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )
  {
    $nxmArr[$row][$col] = $value++;
  }
}

for( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )
{
  $colSum = 1;
  for( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )
  {
    echo $nxmArr[$row][$col]." ";
    $colSum *= $nxmArr[$row][$col];
  }
  echo "Col Sum: $colSum<br>";
}

echo "<br>";

for( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )
{
  $rowSum = 1;
  for( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )
  {
    echo $nxmArr[$row][$col]." ";
    $rowSum *= $nxmArr[$row][$col];
  }
  echo "Row Sum: $rowSum<br>";
}
```

Comment: There are 2 verse of loop / echo that basically does the same calculation. Why do you need to do it twice?

Comment: I need for calculating rows and columns, but I cannot figure how to improve my code and get same results using minimum for loops.

Comment: Why don't you use a single for loop for the result? What is the need of 3 different for-loop?

Comment: First for loop is adding numbers, second for calculating columns, and third for rows. I've tried to use single loop, and I tried with two arrays, but still can't get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this by using

```
$nxmArr = [];
$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;
$value = 1;
$flag = 0; 
for( $row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++ )
{
  for( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ )
  {
    $nxmArr[$row][$col] = $value++; 
    $flag += $nxmArr[$row][$col];
    ($row > 0) 
    ? 
    ($colns[$col] += $nxmArr[$row][$col])
    : 
    ($colns[$col] = $nxmArr[$row][$col])
    ;
  }
  $rowSum[] = $flag;
  $flag = 0;
}
echo 'Columns Sum :-';
print_r($colns);
echo '<hr>';
echo 'Rows sum :-';
print_r($rowSum);
```

Live Demo :- https://3v4l.org/d3ml4

---

**Explanation :-**

1. `$flag += $nxmArr[$row][$col];` This will do the row elements addition one by one and when the single row traversed, assign sum to an array element i.e. `$rowSum[] = $flag;` and make the flag element 0 i.e. `$flag=0`
2. `($row > 0) 
   ? 
   ($colns[$col] += $nxmArr[$row][$col])
   : 
   ($colns[$col] = $nxmArr[$row][$col])`

When the `$row=0`, the code `($colns[$col] = $nxmArr[$row][$col])` will be executes and it will keep the values like `$colns[0]=1,$colns[1]=2,$coln[2]=3,$colns[3]=4`, Now when `$row>0` , it will add the new values to indices `0,1,2,3`

Comment: Yes, that could pass, but the idea is to get expected result without using any function...like I did, but I've used many for loops, and now I'm looking for a way to short my code, and to get same result but with using maybe one nested loop if that is possible...

Comment: Thank you Rakesh for your help! Can you just explain me about ? and :...is that a replacement of if else statement?

Comment: @Developer12345 explaination has been added

Comment: I need to multiply rows and column, without addition...I tried just to change from + to * but I'm not getting right results...

Comment: @Developer12345 you should change `$flag=0` to `$flag=1` at both places, check her https://3v4l.org/P74dj

Comment: Ok, that works...can you tell me how can I write code without using ? and : becuase I never used this kind of method in writing code...

Comment: @Developer12345 this is called ternary operator, shorten of `if...else`